# Python 2.7 unpacking error

Tags: python

I am getting the error message

> badfilesdic = {k: v for k, v in badfilelist} ValueError: need more
>   than 1 value to unpack

I am not sure how to fix it!

```
this is the code:

def badfiles(hasheddic, filesavedin ):

    print hasheddic
    print '\n'
    print filesavedin

    badfilelist = [s.split(' : ') for s in hasheddic]
    badcontentlist = [s.split(' : ') for s in filesavedin]
    badfilesdic = {k: v for k, v in badfilelist}
    badcontentdic = {k: v for v, k in badcontentlist}

    match = ""
    for hashval, filename in badcontentdic.iteritems():
        if filename in badfilesdic:
            match += (hashval + " File Extension:  " + badfilelist[filename]) + "\n"

    return match
```

Comment: the document also looks like this

Comment: 9d377b10ce778c4938b3c7e2c63a229a:contraband_file1.jpg
6bbaa34b19edd6c6fa06cccf29b33125:contraband_file2.jpg
e4e7c3451a35944ca8697f9f2ac037f1:contraband_file3.jpg
1d6d9c72e3476d336e657b50a77aee05:contraband_file4.gif

Comment: You're splitting on `' : '` but your above comment has no spaces.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the code to do?

Comment: Instead of making lists and then turning them into dictionaries, you might as well start with dictionaries: `badfilesdic = dict(s.split(':') for s in hasheddic)` and `badcontentdic = dict(s.split(':')[::-1] for s in filesavedin)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your code:

```
badfilelist = [s.split(':') for s in hasheddic]
```

then

```
badfilesdic = dict(badfilelist) # if you want to have a unique dict
```

or

```
badfilesdic = [{k:v} for k, v in badfilelist] # if you want to have a list of dicts
```

of maybe:

```
badfilesdic = tuple({k:v} for k, v in badfilelist) # if you want to have a tuple of dicts
```

or whatever you like. All you need is to unpack properly your variables.

Comment: I think OP just wants a single dictionary for each list, not many of them.

Comment: He didn't say that in his question. I thought he would split then unpack the values in a dict or many of them. Well, i'll edit my post to fill to your comment.

Comment: `dict((k,v) for k, v in badfilelist)` is just `dict(badfilelist)`.

Comment: You're right. Thanks again. I appreciate your comments a lot.

Comment: And `{{k:v} for k, v in badfilelist}` isn't valid.

Comment: You're right again. I'll test my answer again. Thanks

Comment: In `({k:v} for k, v in badfilelist]` you've got a square bracket at the end, and if you replace that with a parenthesis you'll have a generator. It needs to be prepended with `tuple` (e.g. `tuple({k:v} for...`) to evaluate it into a tuple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129180/discussion-between-nexus66-and-tigerhawkt3).

Comment: I edited my answer. Thanks again. You're awesome @TigerhawhT3